# phpmailer debug output to html variable

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Im looking to use php mailers debug information to display in a webpage. When I enable debugging it just echo's the string. This means that my html is out of order, I wish to therefor output as a variable so I can place the output html where i want it.

```
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A recent change in PHPMailer [allows `Debugoutput` to be a closure](https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-SMTP.html#property_Debugoutput), so you can make it do whatever you like, for example to collect all the debug output and emit it later:

```
$debug = '';
$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {
    $GLOBALS['debug'] .= "$level: $str\n";
};
//...later
echo $debug;
```

Comment: Isn't this missing a `;` after the `}`?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, there appears to currently be a bug in PHPMailer where $str in the function above does not contain the debug output but instead just contains the short error (the same exact thing that's stored in $mail->ErrorInfo). This happens even when it's set to $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;

Comment: I figured it out. Instead of the callback function being called once when there is an error, the callback is called multiple times - once per line of debug info. So you have to make sure that you are **concatenating** the $str variable to your $GLOBALS['debug'] variable as above (instead of assigning the variable like I was) or you'll only get the very last line of debug info... which is usually the same as $mail->ErrorInfo.