# PHPMailer emails NOT sending sometimes because of multiple tests?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am having issues with mail NOT going to all email addresses sometimes. I have been testing from a web-app I built and it is hosted with GoDaddy with "Deluxe" shared hosting level.
Is it possible that I have upset the GoDaddy Email Server gods by submitting too many test email sends??
Is it possible that my emails are being blocked because the servers think my multiple tests are spam? I do receive SOME of the emails....

```
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
// Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2; // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx.prod.phx3.secureserver.net'; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true; // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'cpanelusername'; // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'cpanelpassword'; // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port       = 587; // TCP port to connect to

// Recipients - Names are optional - $mail->setFrom('xxxxxxxxxx@cox.net', 'Peter Henry Lee');
$mail->setFrom('xxxxxxxxxx@cox.net'); // From Address
$mail->addAddress('xxxxxxxxxx@cox.net'); // Recipient 1
$mail->addAddress('xxxxx@cox.net'); // Recipient 2
$mail->addCC('xxxxxxx@cox.net'); // Cc 1 Address
$mail->addCC('xxxxxxxx@cox.net'); // Cc 2 Address
$mail->addBCC('xxxxxxxxx@xxxxesigns.com'); // Bcc Address
// $mail->addReplyTo('xxxxxxxxx@xxxxesigns.com'); // Reply-To Address

// Attachments
include 'retrieve_order.php'; // Retrieves PDF
$mail->addAttachment('receipts/' . $newname); // Adds PDF attachment
 // $mail->addAttachment('img/puppy2.png', 'Puppy is cute!'); // Adds Image attachment with optional name

// Content
$newname       = substr($newname, 0, 11);
$l             = $newname;
$mail->isHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the TEST ' . $l . ' subject line';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the TEST ' . $l . ' HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the TEST ' . $l . ' body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

// Send mail
$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: If the code works sometimes and sometimes not, I would recommend that you contact GoDaddy and aks them. We can't possibly know if you've reached some limit on their servers.

Comment: Unless you can show a difference in SMTP debug output between successful and unsuccessful sends, there is nothing to suggest it's down to your script. In other news, GoDaddy continues its quest to dig its way beyond the bottom of the barrel of hosting services.

Comment: @Synchro Thanks, and I have debug level at 2. Is that the best level, and where are the debug reports saved?

Comment: 2 is fine for SMTP issues, 3 better for connection issues. Debug is output directly, not saved. Most important is to read the troubleshooting guide.

Comment: @Synchro       Is it ok to use "include" or "require" in the PHPMailer script? As you can see in my // Attachments code area, I have an include that retrieves the PDF file and adds it to the mailer. AND, I also use an "include" in my FPDF PDF creation script to add the mailer script in there.... Is it possible those are not being accepted by the PHPMailer script, or at least causing conflicts and making some emails come through and some not??

Comment: Of course you can use include or require wherever you need - PHPMailer will have no effect on that.

Comment: Check the actual response from GoDaddy. The SMTP protocol requires some reasonable error codes & messages that will tell you why/if your message was rejected. Check the debug messages as noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122711/phpmailer-debug-output-to-html-variable